# Should I Use Single Connection or Multiple Connections with QSqlDatabase

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, database-connection

I have dependent and independent classes, I need to create database connections in these classes. As I understand from [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qsqldatabase.html#details), if I create connections in default way, all of them use same connection.

Should I create different database connections for different classes, or should I use same database connection. What are pros and cons?
Thanks.

Comment: Not a Qt/MySQL specialist, but in general. Multiple connections == multiple sessions == multiple outstanding transactions in the DB (plus whatever resource overhead that has). If you do not need multiple parallel transactions, then you do not need multiple connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why @Dummy00001 logged his response as a comment rather than an answer, but I concur with him. If you aren't going to be working with the database in a parallel fashion, you don't need multiple connections, and they will, in fact, be wasteful of resources both in your client library and on the server.